# Vim keyboard shortcut to move windows doesn't work

Tags: vim

I want to focus on the right window by hitting `ctrl l` without having to do `ctrl w` perior to that.

From my (limited) understanding of vim, adding the following to `~/.vimrc` should work:

```
nnoremap <C-J> <C-W>j
nnoremap <C-K> <C-W>k
nnoremap <C-L> <C-W>l
nnoremap <C-H> <C-W>h
```

But it doesn't. Any ideas how to debug this?

**EDIT**

Here's the result of `:verbose nmap <c-j>` as requested in the comments (I don't know what that means btw)

[image]

Comment: Did you source your changes to the file? With Vim open: `:so ~/.vimrc`

Comment: I don't see any problem here. Are you sure your `.vimrc` is being loaded?

Comment: What is the result of `:verbose nmap <c-j>` ? It shows you where `<c-j>` was mapped or remapped. Also see [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2003/how-do-i-debug-my-vimrc-file)

Comment: @perelo I updated the question with the result, I have no idea what it means :O

Comment: @goldylucks `n` means "normal mode mapping"; `<NL>` is the same as `<C-J>` (`:h ctrl-j`); `*` I think means "no recursive" and `<C-W>j` means your mapping is done as you wanted. It's hard to say more :/

Comment: See [how to debug a mapping](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/7722/how-to-debug-a-mapping) from [Vi and Vim SE](https://vi.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Do any of the 4 keybinds work? Which terminal emulator are you using?

Comment: I'm using kitty, which uses all these bindings (see my answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the shortcut for the terminal is overriding the shortcut in vim. I will try to find a way for the terminal to detect if vim is running, and if so, allow the keypress to go through to vim instead of capturing it in the terminal.